# Laravel display image from database

Tags: php, laravel

I have a controller where I upload an image like this:

```
$image = $request->file('image')->store('public/categories');
Category::create([
            'image' => $request->image,
        ]);
```

and I want to display it in the admin section in a table but the images don't load properly:

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
<th scope="row" class="py-4 px-6 font-medium text-gray-900 whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">
    <img src="{{Storage::url($category->image)}}" class="w-16 h-16 rounded" alt="image not loading">
</th>
@endforeach
```

my route for admin table:

```
public function index()
    {
        $categories = Category::all();
        return view('admin.categories.index', compact('categories'));
    }
```

Comment: You're saving `$request->image` to your `categories` table, did you mean to store `$image`? `'image' => $image` instead of `'image' => $request->image`.

Comment: You're right, however the image still doesn't load properly. I'm following a YT video: https://youtu.be/8KaBeq9JzrQ?t=5128 at 1:25:28 you can see the code

Comment: You'll have to debug it then; use your browser's tools to see what URL the image is attempting to be loaded by, and compare that with where the image actually was uploaded to. Hint: You're saving it in `public/categories`, but trying to load it via the `Storage::url()` helper, which would work if it was in the `storage` folder, or symlinked properly.